# Ansible how to run all tasks on localhost except one on remote server

Tags: ansible, devops

I have a playbook that runs multiple tasks on `loacalhost` like below, Except one where I need to store the result in a file to a remote server and use it in the next task as condition based on the content of the file.

What is the best way to do this and how do we define credentials for this server?

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: run task1
      debug: msg="running task on localhost"
    - name: run task 2
      debug: msg="running all others also localhost"
      register: output
    - name: store output in remote storage server
      debug: msg="Copy the content of register output to a file in remote server"
      delegate_to:  "remote.storageserver.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make two plays, and at the end of the first play set the variables you need for the tasks on the remote host. Set `hosts` to only `localhost` for the first play, and `remotehost` for the second play. Include whatever remote tasks you need in the second play. You can also define different credentials this way.

Ex:

```
- name: Local play
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: run task1
      debug: msg="running task on localhost"
    - name: run task 2
      debug: msg="running all others also localhost"
      register: output

- name: Remote play
  hosts: remote.storageserver.com
  tasks:
    - name: store output in remote storage server
      debug: msg="Copy the content of register output to a file in remote server"
```